# Calculating area of a segment in a circle

Tags: python, python-3.x

You are given the diameter across, and the length of the segment or chord. The diameter for my question is 12, and the chord is 10. You have to find the height of the shaded segment, and then print the area. The original formula is `A=2/3ch + h^3/2c`. My classmates got 18 for the area, but when I use my code I get 41.

This is the closest picture representation I can find. However there is a dashed line from `ϴ` to `s`.[image: Image retrieved from wolfram.com]

```
from math import sqrt

diamStr=input("Enter the length of the diameter:   ")

diameter=int(diamStr)

chordStr = input( " Enter the chord length:          ")
chord = int(chordStr)


radius = (diameter/2)

s = sqrt (diameter**2+chord**2)

h = (s/2-radius)

i= (2/3*chord*h)

j=(h**3/2*chord)

area = (i+j)

print (area)
```

Comment: Didn't found any question marks in the question.

Comment: @SargeBorsch It's "Didn't find". (SCNR)

Comment: @glglgl thank you. Sometimes I have problems with English.

Comment: @To_the_oop what kind of equation were you trying to use? Maybe I could convert my solution to that non-understandable equation if you point to some web resources that state that equation as a valid method to calculate segement area...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's something wrong with your formula but if look at the problem with some elementary mathematics you may notice that the angle `ϴ` can be found using the [cosine rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) since we know the 3 lengths *(the two radius and chord length)*

[image: Obtained from mathsisfun.com]

In Python it would be:

```
theta = math.acos((radius**2 + radius**2 - chord**2)/(2*radius**2))
```

Since the variable `theta` is already in radians we can use this formula to calculate the area of the segment :

[image]

which in python would be `area = 1/2 * (theta - math.sin(theta)) * radius**2`

Therefore after merging all of these we come up with a elegant solution:

```
import math

diamStr=input("Enter the length of the diameter:   ")
diameter=int(diamStr)

chordStr = input( " Enter the chord length:          ")
chord = int(chordStr)

radius = (diameter/2)
theta = math.acos((radius**2 + radius**2 - chord**2)/(2*radius**2))

area = 1/2 * (theta - math.sin(theta)) * radius**2

#print(round((area),2))
print(area)
```

If you enter diameter as 12cm and chord length as 10 you'll get `18.880864248381847` but you can round it to any number of decimal places you want by the `round()` function.

eg: `print(round((area),2))` prints `18.88`

Comment: you could simplify to `theta = math.acos(1 - .5 * chord**2 / radius**2)`

Comment: The sine rule is the best I'd reckon `theta = 2 * math.asin(chord/(2*radius))` though takes some time to absorb it